# И еще о национальностях

Tags: словообразование

По какому принципу ставятся окончания множественного числа в названиях национальностей? Почему, например, те же варяг**и**, араб**ы**, грек**и**, но цыган**е**, славян**е**, египтян**е**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что такого замечательного есть в словах **цыгане, славяне, египтяне**, что дает им во множественном числе окончание -е? Ответ простой: состав слова. А точнее суффиксы. В старославянском языке суффиксы -ин-ъ, -Ѣнин-ъ, -ΙΑнин-ъ употреблялись для образования существительных, обозначавших лиц мужского пола по их социальному положению, национальности, происхождению из какой-либо местности (болΙΑринъ, властелинъ, землΙΑнінъ, крьстьΙΑнинъ, римлΙΑнинъ, гражданинъ и т.д.). Те же суффиксы -ин, -анин, -янин используются и сейчас с тем же значением. Но во множественном числе часть суффикса -ин-ъ опускалась, поскольку являлась показателем единичности в составе названных суффиксов. Окончание -е в именительном падеже множественного числа у таких существительных тоже традиционное. В современном языке такое окончание - реликт, остаточное явление старославянской системы склонений существительных.(Это сейчас у нас три склонения, а в старославянском языке их было шесть или пять, по разным источникам).  Что до слов **греки, арабы, варяги**, то они относились к другому склонению. Поэтому окончания отличаются.

Answer (score 4):

Это действительно очень древний и не совсем понятный процесс.
Я только напомню, что на каждое такое правило есть десяток исключений.
Вообще правило - вернее сказать: закономерность - для образования множественного числа от обозначения нациольнальности на -[0], -н, -ин (-енин, -анин) такое.  
*Если в единственном числе -ин отбрасывается, то множестенное имеет окончание -ы:

Грузин-грузины, абазин-абазины, и т.д. 

В противном случае окончание -е:

Славянин - славяне, египтянин - египтяне, армянин - армяне и т.д.*

Исключения: татарин-татары, цыган-цыгане и болгарин-болгары. Кстати, последний случай до недавнего времении образовывался по общему правилу (болгаре), а первые два оспаривались самим Пушкиным, писавшим "цыганы" и "татаре" по общему правилу.

Эта же закономерность наблюдается и для других случаев использрвания суффикса -ин (-енин, -анин), например жителей городов: калужанин-калужане, но там много спорных случаев, это тема необъятная.

Comment: у вас ошибка. в слове грузин ин не отбрасывается.

Comment: @qdinar *в слове грузин ин не отбрасывается.* - ??? "Грузинин"???

Comment: "Если в единственном числе -ин отбрасывается ... Грузин-грузины" - сами написали что отбрасывается, но в обоих числах ин есть.

Comment: @qdinar вы что-то в трех соснах запутались. Сформулируйте вопрос, если он у вас есть. По поводу того, что я написал, мне добавить нечего. Сравните: армяне-армян**ин** - вот вариант с неотброшенным "ин". Грузины-грузин(не грузин**ин**)  - ин "отброшено". И так всюду.

Comment: ну раз там после отбрасывания ин ещё один ин остается, это получается непонятным для читателя. и там 2 примера, и оба такие, поэтому можно подумать что ошибка.

Comment: @qdinar *поэтому можно подумать что ошибка* - вам можно ))). Давайте уже по существу. Формулировку я могу уточнить, если не понятна, не проблема, но ошибки как таковой я не вижу.

Comment: я имел ввиду, что мозг читателя может машинально подумать, что тут писатель просто ошибся, пропустил "не". а иначе почему он (писатель) ясно не написал, что он говорит не об этих "ин", которые явно видны в его примерах, а о тех "ин", которые когда-то были, либо вообще были лишь в теории, но исчезли. для того чтобы подумать о тех ваших "ин", которые в ваших "грузинин", (который вы даже не упомянули, на тот момент), эту вашу теорию ешё знать надо, довольно уверенно, а то оно как-то довольно сомнительно ещё, я вот такого слова никогда не слышал.